# using ffmpeg exe in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg

and am wanting to use ffmpeg as command line direct on windows 7 x64, I tried adding the extension, but unfortunately it did not work for some unknown reason, but the executable worked perfectly, I'm using the exec command, the only problem is that does not work with direct lines, I have to create a file. bat to run the program. this is my doubt.

```
$a = exec('\b.bat');
 if ($a) 
      { 

        echo "Success"."\n"; 
        print $a;
    }else { 

      echo "No good"."\n"; 
      print $a;

      }
```

b.bat

```
ffmpeg -i video.flv -an -ss 00:00:16 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y %a.jpg
```

already tried several alternatives but the only one that worked was with the. bat

```
$a = exec('\windows/system32/ffmpeg.exe ffmpeg -i video.flv -an -ss 00:00:16 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y %a.jpg');
```

Comment: Try using a full path instead of "\windows/system32..."

Something like: "C:/windows/system32..."

Comment: Especially when placing it under Windows/system32 you should check execute rights for your PHP user.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the full path to your .bat file and also make sure to include the full path to ffmpeg.exe in your .bat file.

Comment: the problem is that I do not want to run straight. bat
put the full directory and did not work

Comment: I believe that you misunderstood my solution. You must include the full path to the batch file in your code and you must include the full path to ffmpeg in your batch file. The problem is that the PATH is usually not setup correctly when running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am also working on this `ffmpeg` file to convert my movies and stuff my idea is for people to watch movies for free anyway here is what I use to convert my movies, have a note that when the `ffmpeg.exe` is not in the same folder than the movies then you will need to give a full path or use of ../ to go up a folder and / to a folder for example:

```
 $input_path=   $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $output_result=  "movies/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]).".flv";
 exec("FFMPEG.EXE -i '$input_path' -s 900x400 -r 29.97 -b 1024k -ar 22050 -ab 50k -ac 1    '$output_result'");
```

there I am using scale and rateframe as well as bitrate and sound quality so my input and output I gave them in a variable basically that command you can use as is just give a value to those variables $input and $output. Please note that I am barely working out the idea too so far this is what I have come out with please do not expect excellent results since we are using microsoft windows the results may vary from version to version and you may have to use the command in administrator mode I hope this helps you my email is support@web2021.com if anything let me know man.